# Corrupted symbols with xml encoding iso-8859-1 in POST request

Tags: xml, asp.net-web-api, encoding, corruption

I use this code in asp.net web api controller to save xml content to file:

```
using (var str = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
using (var fileStream = File.Create(@"C:\directory\somename.xml")
{
    await str.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}
```

If I send this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>Förstelärare</root>
```

it's ok. But in this case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<root>Förstelärare</root>
```

I see this in file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<root>FÃ¶rstelÃ¤rare</root>
```

I see problem in encoding. How to fix it properly?
I post requests uisng chrome extension RestClient. In another case we upload data from request stream to ftp server using `WebRequest`. The same problem.
**Update:** another interesting thing - corrupted data looks ok in windows notepad but corrupted in Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

It's encoded correctly, but being **displayed** wrong. This happens all the time between browsers and servers. Sometimes 8859 gets translated, sometimes not. Stick with UTF-8, it seems to be taking prominence. ISO-8859-* was hip last decade.